# Video view issue on android 4.0 and above 

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am trying to play video from streaming url. the code is as following

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity  
{
    private VideoView mVideoView;            
    String videoURL="";
    static Utility utility;
    static Context context;
    MediaController mediaController;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {         
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_player);          
        setupViews();
    }

    private void setupViews() 
    {
        context=VideoPlayer.this;
        utility=new Utility(VideoPlayer.this);
        isActivityisRunning=true;
        showProgressDialog("Loading video..");
        videoURL=getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");            
        mVideoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        mediaController=new MediaController(context);            
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                hideProgressDialog();

                if(bIsOnPausedCalled)
                    mVideoView.seekTo(LastDuration);
                    mVideoView.start();                     
                    mVideoView.requestFocus();  
                    bIsOnPausedCalled=false;
                    LastDuration=0;
                }
            });

           mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
                {
                    finish();
                }
            }); 


           mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() 
           {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) 
            {
                utility.hideProgressDialog();
                return false;
            }
        });

           playVideoFile();      
        } 

    public static void showDialog(String Message)
    {       
                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();  
                alertDialog.setTitle(Constant.DialogTitle);  
                alertDialog.setMessage(Message);  
                alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                alertDialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {  
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                          {             
                             dialog.dismiss();                          
                          } 
                }); 
                if(isActivityisRunning)
                    alertDialog.show();
                else
                    utility.showToast(Message);
    }

    static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    static AlertDialog alertDialog;

    public  void showProgressDialog(String Message)
    {   
            hideProgressDialog();
            progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setTitle(Constant.DialogTitle);
            progressDialog.setMessage(Message);                         
            if(isActivityisRunning)
                progressDialog.show();
            else
                utility.showToast(Message);
    }

    public static boolean isActivityisRunning;
    public static boolean showProgressDialog;


    public static boolean bIsOnPausedCalled=false;
    public static int LastDuration=0;

        @Override
        protected void onPause() 
        {   

            hideProgressDialog();
            bIsOnPausedCalled=true;
            isActivityisRunning=false;
            if (mVideoView != null)
            {       
                if(LastDuration==0)
                {
                    LastDuration=mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
                    mVideoView.suspend();
                    mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
                }               
            }
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() 
        {

            isActivityisRunning=true;
                if(bIsOnPausedCalled)
                {                       
                    setupViews();               
                }
                super.onResume();       
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() 
        {
            super.onDestroy();
            try 
            {               
                if (mVideoView != null) 
                {   
                    mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                    mVideoView=null;                
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    isActivityisRunning=false;
                     bIsOnPausedCalled=false;
                     LastDuration=0;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) 
            {}              
        }


    public static void hideProgressDialog()
    {
        if(progressDialog!=null)
        {
            if(progressDialog.isShowing())
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }           
        }
    }


    private void playVideoFile() 
        {

                try 
                {                   
                    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoURL));
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    utility.hideProgressDialog();
                    if (mVideoView != null) 
                    {                   
                        mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                    }
                }
            }
```

This works fine on android device having version below 4.0 (with pause and resume with sleep mode button).
but when i am trying to play video on android phone having version4.0 or later 
video will play fine but when phone goes to sleep mode and resume back from sleep mode 
the video view size became half of screen. as following[image]

please help?

Thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing is all correct but you have applied setContentView(R.layout.video_player); 
only ones ,even though video is resumed.
so code should be

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{         
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                
    setupViews();
}

private void setupViews() 
{
    setContentView(R.layout.video_player);  
    context=VideoPlayer.this;
    -----
    ------
}
```

Instead of

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{         
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.video_player);       
    setupViews();
}

private void setupViews() 
{
    context=VideoPlayer.this;
    -----
    ------
}
```